# How make option menu like web in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I make footer that consists images.I want when click on image of footer menu opens like this.(Android)

[image: How make menu like this]

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, this is not web and you need to look at methods to achieve this natively in Android.

Read up [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Try to use sub-menu, check [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)